# Prevent ignoring of some properties of Model by toJson overriding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I save the records, I need the uid properties for the initial rows; because of I can assign a value each of them through the uid.
However, toJson overriding forces to ignore some properties like dirty, uid, etc...
How can I prevent this? Or How can I find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** persist the `uid` on the backend or override it.

The `uid` is an internal mechanism used by Kendo UI to track its widgets and widget components to allow user interaction and component functionality. Each `uid` is generated dynamically every time the widget is rendered, so, attempting to do what your thinking of doing won't work.

The proper solution is you should assign your own unique `id` property to your records and persist it on the server/client. Then, when a change is made client-side, you post the record data along with its unique `id`, find the associated record by `id` in the backend database, and update the associated record data in the database.

Comment: There are some points where you happen right. I asked this question due a problem that I have. I prefered to use batch editing. Some rows are not entered into to DB before, thus they have not any record id. When I send these to server at once with ajax  I should continue to page without refresh. And these all should take their id that return from the server.  I should assign record ids to these  rows. I should establish a relation between these grid's rows and resultset that returns from server.   Which way except this can help me? Certainly an unique value belongs the these rowss can help me.